# Velocity-dependent potential under generalized coordinates transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, coordinate-systems, covariance

If under some generalized coordinates the force can be written as:

$$Q_j =-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}+\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right).$$

Then can the force always be written in that form under any other generalized coordinates for that problem?

(If not then the potential about EM force can only apply to $x,y,z$ coordinates or a few other coordinates but not any coordinates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For geometric theories, the Lagrangian $L$, the kinetic term $T$ and the velocity-dependent potential $U$ are scalars, i.e. invariant under change of generalized coordinates. This is e.g. the case for E&M.

Similarly, the Lagrange equations are covariant, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118768/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280143/2451) related Phys.SE posts.