# Help with the proof of the independence of the form of Lagrange equation wrt. choice of coordinates

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, covariance

I am reading about Lagrange-Euler equation [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-09-classical-mechanics-iii-fall-2014/lecture-notes/MIT8_09F14_Chapter_1.pdf).

When they prove that the formula is independent of the choice of coordinate, there is this reasoning, but I could not understand (probably my calculus background is not good):

[image]

Maybe this is simple, but could someone please explain it?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375322/2451