# What will happen if we take up Cartesian Coordinates in Lagrangian Formulation instead of Generalized Coordinates?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Why do we actually need generalized coordinates? Is it a mathematical manipulation only or does it serve physical purpose? And will principle of stationary action stay valid if we use cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Friendly reminder: comments are for improving the question. Post answers as answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a particle $m$ with coordinates $x,y,z$ in a field $U(x,y,z)$, then the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal L = \frac m2(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2) - U(x,y,z)
$$
will lead you to the well-known equations:
$$
m\ddot x=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x},\qquad
m\ddot y=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial y},\qquad
m\ddot z=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}.
$$

However, if you take a slightly complicated system: two balls $m$ connected with a rod of length $l=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}$, then the equations in Cartesian coordinates become complicated:
$$
\mathcal L = \frac m2(\dot x_1^2+\dot y_1^2+\dot x_2^2+\dot y_2^2)+\lambda\Big((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2-l^2\Big),\\
m\ddot x_1 = \lambda(x_1-x_2),\qquad m\ddot x_2 = -\lambda(x_1-x_2),\\
m\ddot y_1 = \lambda(y_1-y_2),\qquad m\ddot y_2 = -\lambda(y_1-y_2)
$$

You have a linear differential equation of 4th order you have to solve. It's not impossible but it will take a while.

Let's take generalized coordinates $x,y,\theta$: $x_1=x+\frac l2\cos\theta$, $y_1=y+\frac l2\sin\theta$, $x_2=x-\frac l2\cos\theta$, $y_2=y-\frac l2\sin\theta$:
$$
\mathcal L = \frac m2\left(\left(\dot x-\dot\theta\frac l2\sin\theta\right)^2+\left(\dot y+\dot\theta\frac l2\cos\theta\right)^2+\left(\dot x+\dot\theta\frac l2\sin\theta\right)^2+\left(\dot x-\dot\theta\frac l2\cos\theta\right)^2\right) = \\
m(\dot x^2 + \dot y^2) + \frac{ml^2}4\dot\theta^2,\\
2m\ddot x = 0,\qquad 2m\ddot y = 0,\qquad \frac{ml^2}2\ddot\theta = 0.
$$
So much simpler. Thus, the ability to have generalized coordinates adds great flexibility to analyze and solve systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the context of Newtonian mechanics of $N$ rectangular position coordinates ${\bf r}_1, \ldots, {\bf r}_N$, [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $q^1,\ldots, q^n, $ are usually introduced as a way to eliminate $3N-n$ [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) $$f_m({\bf r},t)~=~0, \qquad m~\in~\{1,\ldots,3N-n \}.$$
2. Returning to OP's main question: A [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) $$L({\bf r}(q,t),\dot{\bf r}(q,\dot{q},t),t)$$ of generalized coordinates $q^j$ may equivalently be replaced by a Lagrangian
   $$ L({\bf r},\dot{\bf r},t)+\sum_{m=1}^{3N-n}\lambda^m f_m({\bf r},t) $$
   of rectangular position coordinates ${\bf r}_i$ and [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda^m$.
3. Of course the larger picture is that the Lagrangian formalism is independent of the choice of coordinate system, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118768/2451) Phys.SE post. So one may use the most convenient coordinate system in any given situation.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 1.